# Is there a more F# idiomatic way to create all combinations from two sequences

Tags: f#

I have the following code:

```
    let orders = Array2D.init<AnalyzerOrder> (sentimentRanges |> Seq.length) (triggerRanges |> Seq.length) (fun x y -> AnalyzerOrder.empty)
    sentimentRanges |> Seq.iteri (fun x sentimentPeriod ->
        triggerRanges |> Seq.iteri (fun y triggerPeriod ->
            (
                let settings =
                    {
                        ...
                    }

                orders.[x, y] <- settings
            )
        )
    )
```

It takes 2 sequences, and create an order list with all the combinations and put them in a grid.

Is there a built-in way to create all the combinations from 2 sequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the [implementation](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/24c798bfcee5d6f91ae2c19888baeb9946744c3a/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1020) of `Seq.allPairs` you will discover that it boils down to `Seq.collect` for the outer loop and `Seq.cache`/`Seq.map` for the inner. This can be generalized to two functions `mapc`/`iterc`, who take a function `f:('a -> 'b -> 'c)` or action `f:('a -> 'b -> unit)` as their first argument.

```
let mapc f xs ys = Seq.collect (fun x -> Seq.map (f x) (Seq.cache ys)) xs
// val mapc : f:('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> xs:seq<'a> -> ys:seq<'b> -> seq<'c>

let iterc f xs ys = Seq.iter (fun x -> Seq.iter (f x) (Seq.cache ys)) xs
// val iterc : f:('a -> 'b -> unit) -> xs:seq<'a> -> ys:seq<'b> -> unit
```

We could use them to generate the hyperinflation sequence for banknotes (OEIS [A051109](http://oeis.org/A051109)), or - more to the question - imperatively fill the values of an `[,]`.

```
mapc (*) (Seq.initInfinite (pown 10I)) [1I; 2I; 5I] |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.toList
// val it : System.Numerics.BigInteger list =
//   [1; 2; 5; 10; 20; 50; 100; 200; 500; 1000]

let a2 = Array2D.zeroCreate 3 3
iterc (fun i j -> a2.[i,j] <- 1) [0..2] [0..2]
```

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
let initArray f s1 s2 = Array2D.init (Array.length s1) (Array.length s2) (fun a b -> f s1.[a] s2.[b] )

initArray (+) [|1;2;3|] [|1;2;3;4|] //where f is a sum function in this case
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just to list all combinations, you can use the built-in function `Seq.allPairs` (exists in `Array` and `List` variants as well). If you want to create a two-dimensional array, you should do as @FRocha suggests.